# can't html input tag send file .hvic type image extention in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, css

im web developer. 
i know ios 11 update about image extenction.
and i developed my webpage to use this skill -> client : html + css + javascript / backend : php7 + mariaDB

then, i use html tag for image upload to server like this....

```
  <input type="file" id="camera" name="camera" capture="camera" accept="image/*" style="width:120px"/>
```

and, i send to server capture image for use php7 like this

```
<?php 
if($_FILES['camera']['error'] > 0){
    echo $_FILES['camera']['error'];
}else{
    $_FILES['camera']['name']; 
    $uploaddir = '../../uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['camera']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['camera']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="<?php echo $_FILES['camera']['name']; ?>">
```

there was nothing about $_FILES['camera']['error']; log.
and i checked 
$_FILES['camera']['tmp_name'] , $_FILES['camera']['name'] logs.

there was nothing to fix things....

finally i found about '.heic' ios 11 image extention.

so i want to know can't i send my .heic image to server for use html input tag and php7?
( i checked safari browser and chrome browser. maybe this is not browser issue, because i tested safari browser in laptop.upload .jpg and .png file to server without camera capture)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set your form type to  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: sure, i set enctype="multipart/form-data" option my form tag and i checked transferred  successfully another image format. hmm.... maybe you think this is not image format issue. right?

Comment: Have you checked your PHP file size, memory & POST restrictions for your server?

Comment: sure, i checked nginx's and php7's max_file_size but i didnt check about POST restrictions. what is this? this is nginx's option?

Comment: Yes, php has a maximum POST size setting as well.  It's post_max_size in your php.ini.

Comment: ah, sure. i checked  maximum post size and max file size in php.ini too

Comment: Have you tried printing out your entire $_POST to see what exactly is being put in there?

Comment: i confirmed $_FILES['camera']['tmp_name'] <- this for echo, but im not confirm about $_POST. how can i confirm this?

Comment: try print_r($_POST); to see what's being put in POST.  Might help you understand where your issue is at.

Comment: you mean print_r($_FILES['camera']['tmp_name'])??

Comment: oh, i got it. error number is 0...then. this mean no error generated...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

if you capture image in iphone and android. your tmp_image name is just "image.jpg" or "image.png"(this can be canged  your phone's environment)

so i saw covered image.png in server!

finally, you must changed your pic's name index+tmp_image name.....

@Mason Stedman

thanks for your help ^0^